# How to get data from unopened Workbook?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula:

```
=COUNTIF('[abc.xlsx]sheet1'!$A$2:$A$50000,"<>")
```

When I enter it I get #Value!.
but when I open that workbook it appears to work.

How can I make it work without having the second workbook Open at all?

Comment: I believe this is function based. I don't think `COUNTIF` allows it but `VLOOKUP` does.

Comment: include the full path not just the name. something like `'C:\Users\me\Documents\[abc.xlsx]sheet1'!$A$2:$A$50000`

Comment: it automatically produces it for me, but it still gives #Value!

Comment: It is definitely the fault of COUNTIF see here for list: https://excelribbon.tips.net/T006035_Functions_that_Can_Access_Closed_Workbooks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COUNTIF will not reference a closed book, but SUMPRODUCT will:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C:\Users\me\Documents\[abc.xlsx]sheet1'!$A$2:$A$50000<>""))
```

Change the path to the correct path.